# Excute command in gulp for sub folder

Tags: node.js, gulp, child-process, npm-install

My project is structured as follows:

```
myapp
 -server.js
 -test
 --testcontent
 ---package.json
 -package.json
```

I have two `package.json` files and I want to run `npm install` on the `package.json` inside the `testcontent` folder.

If in the command line I go to `myapp/test/testcontent` and run `npm install` it works and it creates a new folder `node_modules` with the dependencies from the correct `package.json`. How can that be done from within gulp?

I tried the following but it uses the `package.json` in `myapp` not the one in the `testcontent` sub folder:

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
    var options = {
        continueOnError: true, // default = false, true means don't emit error event
        pipeStdout: true, // default = false, true means stdout is written to file.contents
        customTemplatingThing: "test" // content passed to gutil.template()
    };
    var reportOptions = {
        err: true, // default = true, false means don't write err
        stderr: true, // default = true, false means don't write stderr
        stdout: true // default = true, false means don't write stdout
    }
    gulp.src('test/testcontent/')
        .pipe(exec('npm install' , options))
        .pipe(exec.reporter(reportOptions));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gulp-exec` is the wrong tool for this job. In fact the authors of the `gulp-exec` plugin [explicitly advise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-exec) against using it the way you are doing:

> **Note:** If you just want to run a command, just run the command, don't use this plugin

Instead you use the node.js built-in [`child_process.spawn()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options). You can pass the directory where the command should be executed using the `cwd` option:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

gulp.task('default', function(done) {
  spawn('npm', ['install'], { cwd: 'test/testcontent/', stdio: 'inherit' })
    .on('close', done);
});
```

Comment: Thanks , so how do I pipe it to other process?lets say I wan to pipe it like thisreturn gulp
        .src(config.alljs)
         .pipe($.if(args.verbose, $.print()))

Comment: What do you mean "pipe it to another process"? Do you want to send stdout of "npm install" to another process? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Your example makes no sense. What does printing file names have to do with executing "npm install"? The two aren't related at all.

Comment: For example if you want to do the npm install and also want to copy files etc,how would you do it?

Comment: You write one task to copy the files and one task to execute "npm install". Then you execute both of those tasks. Since both operations have absolutely nothing in common they should be in separate tasks.

Comment: but if for example I want that it run by <b>default</b> spawn & copy & run mochaTest how would you do it? can you please provide example?

Comment: No, not in this post. I answered your original question. You're asking a completely different question now. Make a new post for that.